# xsl attribute namespace

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
  <artwork classification="12" href="1.jpg"/>
  <artwork classification="10" href="2.jpg"/>
</content>
```

When applying the xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                >

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@href">
    <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
  <artwork classification="12" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="1.jpg"/>
  <artwork classification="10" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="2.jpg"/>
</content>
```

whereas I need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <artwork classification="12"  xlink:href="1.jpg"/>
  <artwork classification="10"  xlink:href="2.jpg"/>
</content>
```

How should I modify my xsl to get the result I need?

I use xalan XSLT processor.

Comment: Just as a note: *strictly speaking* those two XML documents you showed are equivalent. If by "need" you mean "the consumer fails to parse document #1 correctly and parses #2 just fine", then the consumer is broken and should be fixed. Still, producing #2 is definitely cleaner.

Comment: Actually the two documents are not equivalent; it would be very poor design for a recipient to handle them differently, but they are not canonically equivalent according to the Canonical XML rules, so such an application is not actually broken.

Comment: They may not be canonically equivalent, but they are semantically equivalent.  Downstream apps should not process them differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need just to match the elements for which you want the namespace declared. The processor will apply the namespace for you.

---

**XSLT 1.0** tested under **MSXSL 4.0** (and also tested as **XSLT 2.0** under **Saxon-HE 9.2.1.1J**)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    >

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <content>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </content>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@href">
        <xsl:attribute name="xlink:href">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note the reason this works is that a literal result element (`<content>`) acquires copies of all the in-scope namespaces declared in the stylesheet, whereas an element produced using `xsl:copy` does not.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: Thanks I wasnt able to explain that with clarity in the answer and to my self either. Now I am.